# adding an object to an array inside an array with useReducer

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

reducer:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'addAnotherBox':
            return ????state[action.index] = [...state[action.index] + object;
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  }
```

hook

```
const [listState, listDispatch] = useReducer(reducer, list)
```

initial states/ variables

```
let object = {
    comment:""
}
let box = [object]
let list = [box, []]
```

function:

```
const AddBox = (e, index) => {
    listDispatch({type:"addAnotherBox", index})
}
```

button:

```
            { listState.map((data, index)=> (
<Button variant="outlined" onClick={(e) => AddBox(e, index)}>
    Add box </Button> ))}
```

My problem is that the return.

I have no idea what to put there, i am inexperienced with useReducer and the mutation of arrays in state seems to be worse.

I know if it was just adding something to an array i could go:

```
[...state, object]
```

but as it is so heavily nested how would you change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in one line, but you can do it step by step.

```
case 'addAnotherBox':
    let stateCopy = [...state]; //copy the actual state
    stateCopy[action.index] = state[action.index] ? [...state[action.index], object] : [object]; //if state[action.index] already exists it adds your object, if it does not exist yet it creates a new array containing your object
    return stateCopy; // return stateCopy as the new state
```

Comment: TypeError: state[action.index] is not iterable

Comment: Ok, I thought your state was an array, insead of let stateCopy = [...state] you need let stateCopy = {...state}, I'll update my answer

Comment: its an array of arrays of objects. I'm adding object to one of the arrays.

Comment: ah, sorry. I updated the info. The initial state is list. For some reason that wasn't included.

Comment: I think I understand the issue. The code I provided was trying to destructure state[action.index], but it was null (explaining the "is not iterable" error). I added a condition to check if state[action.index} is null

Comment: you were 100% right both times. The problem was i did this

onclick={(index) => function(index)} instead of  onClick={()=>function(index)}